# This is strange in dbml designer Column name and Enttiy Name is different

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, linq, linq-to-sql

You know we are writing codes. on the other hand; we are changing DBML files if add or change database table. i droped my tables and added new tables. My DBML does not include  new columns names. in My Database ENG_MAINWP_SELECTED_X is not the same as DBML this column ,n my dbml : ENG_MAINWP_SELECTED_X_

Why this strange behavior occurs? So  Save method does not run How can i do that? if take column in server explorer and add dbml every thing must be the same...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you put a space character after M_H ? If yes, sometimes I saw that _ comes because of space character

Comment: i solved old question you know : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174393/loop-structure-to-save-data-in-context-with-addwithvalue-method

Comment: yusuf I added you before too. But I cant see you online.

Comment: can you send empty message to me on facebook or msn included msn address